# Gallery div overlaps footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay so I'm a beginner with coding. I downloaded Galereya Jquery script. It works, but it overlaps all the other content that is under it in the code. I tried changing the overflow and the position, but nothing seems to work. When I add it in another div the grid stops working. Yes I could add a height px, but not all my pages are the same height (and mobile version problem).

**The problem only appears when I add this gallery code. If I add other content, that doesn't overlap.**

Here are the codes I'm using.

```js
        $(function() {
            $('#galleryherepls').galereya();
        });
```

```css
/* Gallery (begin) */
.galereya {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.galereya *,
.galereya-slider * {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    .galereya-clearfix {
        clear: both;
    }

    .galereya-top {
        
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10000;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        background: transparent;
    }
        /* Gallery category select(begin) */
        .galereya-cats {
            display: block;
            overflow: auto;
            width: 135px;
            height: 30px;
            padding-top: 4px;
            margin: 10px auto 0 auto;

            list-style: none;

            cursor: pointer;

            color: #1a1a1a;
            background: #e8e8e8;
        }

            .galereya-cats-item {
                display: none;

                padding: 1px 25px 1px 10px;

                border-top: 1px solid #959595;
            }

                .galereya-cats-item span {
                    font-size: 10pt;

                    display: block;
                    overflow: hidden;

                    width: 93%;

                    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
                    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
                    text-overflow: ellipsis;
                    text-transform: capitalize;
                }

            .galereya-cats-item:first-child {
                display: block;

                border: none;
                background: url('/images/galereya-arrow_down.png') no-repeat 90% 50%;
                background-size: 15px 10px;
            }

        .galereya-cats.open {
            height: auto;
        }

            .galereya-cats.open .galereya-cats-item:first-child {
                background: url('/images/galereya-arrow_up.png') no-repeat 90% 45%;
                background-size: 15px 10px;
            }

            .galereya-cats.open .galereya-cats-item {
                display: block;

                padding: 10px 25px 10px 10px;
            }
        /* Gallery category select(end) */

    /* Gallery grid(begin) */
    .galereya-grid {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin: auto;

    }

        .galereya-cell {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            overflow: hidden;

            width: 150px;
            padding: 0 1px; /* Webkit padding on transition fix */

            cursor: pointer;
        }

            .galereya-cell-img,
            .galereya-cell-desc {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .galereya-cell-img {
                display: block;
                margin:10px;
                width: 150px;

                image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
            }

            .galereya-cell-desc {
                font-size: 10pt;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                margin:10px;
                display: none;

                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 20px 10px;

                text-align: center;

                color: #fff;
                background-color: #373737;
                opacity: 0;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
                -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
                -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
                transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
            }

                .galereya-cell-desc-title {
                    font-weight: bold;
                }

        .galereya-cell-overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;


            overflow: hidden;

            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-out;

        }

        .galereya-cell:hover {
            z-index: 1000;
        }

            .galereya-cell:hover .galereya-cell-desc {
                bottom: 10px;
                opacity: 50;
            }

            .galereya-cell:hover .galereya-cell-overlay {
            }

            .galereya-cell.wave .galereya-cell-overlay{

            }
    /* Gallery grid(end) */

    /* Gallery slider(begin) */
    .galereya-slider {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 1000000;

        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;

        background: transparent;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s ease-out;
        transition: transform .5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: none;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(110%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(110%);
        -ms-transform: translate(110%);
        -o-transform: translateX(110%);
        transform: translateX(110%);
    }

    .galereya-slider.opened {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0);
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

        .galereya-slider-nav {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;

            width: 48px;
            height: 100%;

            cursor: pointer;

            opacity: 0;
            background-color: #000;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: 12px 30px;
            -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
            -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
            transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
        }

        .galereya-slider-nav.left { left: 0; background-image: url(/images/galereya-arrow_prev.png); }
        .galereya-slider-nav.right { right: 0; background-image: url(/images/img/galereya-arrow_next.png); }

        .galereya-slider-nav:active {
            opacity: 0.15;
            -webkit-transition: none;
            -moz-transition: none;
            -o-transition: none;
            transition: none;
        }

        .galereya-slider-desc {
            font-size: 10pt;

            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;

            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            width: 100%;

            text-align: center;

            color: #fff;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
        }

            .galereya-slider-desc-title {}

        .galereya-slider-close,
        .galereya-slider-play {
            position: absolute;

            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;

            cursor: pointer;

            opacity: 0.15;
            background-size: 35px 35px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
            -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
            transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
        }
        .galereya-slider-close:active,
        .galereya-slider-play:active {
            opacity: 0.3;
            -webkit-transition: none;
            -moz-transition: none;
            -o-transition: none;
            transition: none;
        }
        .galereya-slider-close {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;

            background-image: url('/images/galereya-close.png')
        }
        .galereya-slider-play {
            top: 0;
            right: 0;

            background-image: url('/images/galereya-play.png');
        }
        .galereya-slider-play.pause {
            background-image: url('/images/galereya-pause.png');
        }

        .galereya-slider-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

            .galereya-slider-slide {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
    
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;

                overflow: hidden;

                text-align: center;

                background: #fff url('/images/black_lozenge.png');
                background-size: 38px 38px;


                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease-out;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s ease-out;
                transition: transform .5s ease-out;
                -o-transition: none; /*Sorry Opera, you are slow enough*/
            }

                .galereya-slide-loader {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;

                    margin-left: -50px;
                    margin-top: -6px;
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 12px;

                    opacity: 0.15;
                    background: url('/images/galereya-slider-loader.gif') no-repeat center;
                }

                .galereya-slide-img {
                    max-width: 100%;
                    max-height: 100%;
                }

            .galereya-slider-slide.next {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(110%);
                -moz-transform: translateX(110%);
                -ms-transform: translate(110%);
                -o-transform: translateX(110%);
                transform: translateX(110%);
            }
            .galereya-slider-slide.current {}
            .galereya-slider-slide.prev {}
/* Gallery slider(end) */
/* Gallery (end) */

/*Media queries for hi-res devices*/
@media
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
(min-resolution: 192dpi){
    .galereya-slider-close {
        background-image: url('/images/galereya-close@2x.png');
    }

    .galereya-slider-play {
        background-image: url('/01/images/galereya-play@2x.png');
    }

    .galereya-slider-play.pause {
        background-image: url('/01/images/galereya-pause@2x.png');
    }

    .galereya-slider-nav.left { background-image: url(/01/images/galereya-arrow_prev@2x.png); }
    .galereya-slider-nav.right { background-image: url(/01/images/galereya-arrow_next@2x.png); }

    .galereya-slider-slide {
        background-image: url('../img/black_lozenge_@2X.png');
    }
}

/* Other devices and screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    .galereya-cell,
    .galereya-cell-img {
        width: 300px;
    }

    .galereya-cell-desc {
        display: block;
    }

    .galereya-slider {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-out;
        transition: transform 1s ease-out;
        -o-transition: none; /*Sorry Opera, you are slow enough*/
    }

    .galereya-slider-nav { opacity: 0.05; }

    .galereya-slider-slide {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-out;
        transition: transform 1s ease-out;
        -o-transition: none; /*Sorry Opera, you are slow enough*/
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    .galereya-cats.open .galereya-cats-item {
        padding: 1px 25px 1px 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/domtastic/0.12.1/domtastic.min.js"></script>
<div id="galleryherepls">

        <img src="/images/rosest.jpg"
            alt="Title here"
            title="My mind is a Mess"
            data-desc="10-08-2016"
            data-category="Vector"
            data-fullsrc="/images/roses.jpg"
        />        
       
        <img src="/images/pigst.jpg"
            alt="Flying Pigs"
            data-desc="05-07-2016"
            data-category="Vector"
            data-fullsrc="/images/pigst.png"
        />


</div>
```

I'm going insane. I really need help..

Footer:

```html
#footer { margin: auto; margin-bottom:10px;  color: #fff; background: #323232; width: 980px; height: 20px; padding:10px; clear:both; text-align: center;}
```

Comment: Do you have any absolute positioning on your own elements? - What are the elements that are being covered and what styles are applied to them?

Comment: @BenLonsdale I only have this problem with this code. I can add any content, and it doesn't overlap the footer. Only with this code it's overlapping. If I change the overflow in hidden, it doesn't overlap. But then I need to determine the height in px, something I don't want to do because all my pages are different heights.

Comment: can you show which styles you have applied to your footer? We at least need to rule that out

Comment: Added that to the original post. But it's not just the footer it's overlapping. It's all the content I put under it in the code.

Comment: Is this live somewhere? I'd like to debug a working example.

Comment: are you using bootstrap? if so you could wrap your div in a clearfix like so:<div class="clearfix"><div id="galleryherepls">images go here</div></div>... see if that works?

Comment: @SergChernata http://mystico.nl/meubels/banken/

Comment: @GhislaineDamiënne it's quite a mess tbh, I can't tell what is going on. My recommendation is to disable your other scripts and then enable one by one, stepping through the code and the entire process. If this goes into a chat, I'll tell you more there.

Comment: @SergChernata I know I already started cleaning it up when I send it to you! I got a much cleaner page http://salon.mystico.nl/informatie/  and it's the same problem there (removed the footer because of it). So my guess it's the script codes and not my page. But yeh maybe I just have to search for a better script  -,-

Comment: @GhislaineDamiënne The new link you provided looks completely fine to me. I don't see any problems.

Comment: @BenLonsdale I don't, I used skeleton for one website.. but this script is probably the problem. On the demo page they also don't have a footer or any content under it. So I'm gonna search for something better.

Comment: @SergChernata it works fine as long as I don't want to add a footer of any other content after it in the code lol.. because that will show up behind the images.

Answer (score 0):

[It's a bug](https://github.com/VodkaBears/galereya/issues/13) with `0.0.93` version you're using and should be resolved in `0.9.94`.

Get it from [their github page](https://github.com/VodkaBears/galereya/blob/master/src/js/jquery.galereya.js) as their plugin website is still serving the old version.